# Understanding the positivity to the solution of the SDE $dX_t= adt+\sqrt{ \vert X_t \vert}dW_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to reason that the(I am quite sure that my reasoning is fallacious but I can't see why) solution of the SDE

$$dX_t= adt+\sqrt{\vert X_t\vert }dW_t$$ with $X_0=2a$ and $a>0$ is non-negative intuitively.

Assuming that a strong solution to this SDE exists( which follows from a result by V. P Zubchenco ), we know that the solution is continuous and hence for every $\omega \in C[0,\infty)$, $X(\omega)$ starts at $a$ and when a negative push by the brownian increment pushes it closer to zero, the variance which is proportional to $X_t$ decreases and at the moment it hits $0$(the brownian perturbation goes out of play), and  the positive drift comes into play and pushes $X(\omega)$ away from $0$. Since $X$ is continuous , it cant jump to a negative value.

I know that the brownian perturbation can take very large negative values with small probabilities but continuity of $X$ shouldnt allow it to jump and become negative. I am not sure if I am clear enough and if my question is comprehensible. I want to understand the problem in my argument.

Comment: What does the equation even mean if you don't assume that $X_t \geq 0$? What is $\sqrt X_t$ without this assumption?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It starts from a positive value...?

Comment: I may be wrong but this is my understanding: you are assuming that solution exists, so you are assuming that $\sqrt X_t$ makes sense.  I don't understand what is left to be proved.

Comment: Yes it starts from a positive value and I agree the equation does not make sense , but as in the square root mean reverting case they first prove the existence of solutions and then show that its positive almost surely . They  argue the positivity of the square root process as a smart application of Ito's lemma but I am trying to understand why do we even need to use it and if its not intuitively positive when its starts from a positive value

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, I misunderstood you, and what the OP says right above is what I had in mind (write the equation with $\sqrt{|X_t|}$, prove positivity, get rid of the absolute sign).

Comment: @AddSup If you insert the absolute value sign the question surely makes sense, but as stated by OP the question does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, absolutely, I understand what you meant. My bad!

Comment: So if I put an absolute value inside the square root, would my reasoning about the solution being positive work? I modified the question

Comment: Maybe there's a better/right way, but my guess is you can probably try a comparison lemma against a square-root process because we know the condition for positivity for square-root processes.

Comment: Square root processes are always non negative . I am just trying to understand what is wrong in this reasoning and why do the authors argue using ito’s lemma to show the non negativity . They arguments causes me to suspect that my reasoning is incorrect .

Comment: I, once again mistakenly, thought you're concerned about X touching zero. (I learned to mean strict positivity by "positivity".) Given repeated mistakes, I better just keep my mouth shut, but for what it's worth, $dX=\sqrt{|X|}dW$ has strong uniqueness, and the obvious solution is zero (Karatzas Shreve p. 292). Then by comparison (ibid, p.293), your process is nonnegative.

Comment: I agree that its non-negative using example 2.15 pg 292 and proposition 2.18 293(as you mentioned). My question pertains to my whether my intuitive reasoning  is correct(as explained in the question above). I already know that its non-negative , I want to know if my reasoning is fallacious/too simplistic. Thank you for you time and help

Comment: "I want to understand the problem in my argument." Who says that there is a problem? Your intuition is correct; you might however notice that your reasoning does not provide a rigorous proof since the stochastic integral  is not defined in a pathwise sense (i.e. you cannot reason like this for fixed $\omega$).

Comment: @saz that’s is exactly what I was looking for . Thank you for the nice comment .  You come to my rescue every single time .